# InstallShield add dll not to INSTALLDIR and register it

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I'm a newbie to installshield and I want to add a new .dll to my .ism file, the issue is that I need to add it inside `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Triedit\` while installing and register it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you able to install it at another location?

Comment: What makes you think, that `Microsoft Shared` is a directory, you are meant to fiddle with? This is **clearly** territory, you are not supposed to touch. If Microsoft wants you to install the DLL you are looking to install, they will provide it as an MSI or MSM. If a redistributable isn't available, you are likely to run into legal issues as well.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for making me look some more. :) i have found an msi file :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more research and found that an msi file is available for those who need to use DHTML editing control thanks to IInspectable. I'll just add it to my installshield and that's it.
for those who encounter issues that include TriEdit.dll i suggest you read the following thread [MSDN Documentation DHTMLEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663363.aspx)

If you just wand to download the msi file that will solve this issue:
[Microsoft downloading center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8956)

have fun :)